# My question is about the possiblitiy of going overdrawn by mistake if account is hacked

Tags: wallet

I am new to crypto  currencies and wondered if ones online wallet is hacked and coins stolen could the hacker make you go overdrawn by spending coins you don't have?  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can never spend more coins than a wallet controls, there is no 'overdrawing an account' in bitcoin. You either control the keys that can spend some coins, or you don't.

Comment: Many thanks is that the same for all crypto currencies

Comment: There are a large number of cryptocurrencies out there, I do not know if that is the case for every single one of them. That said, if a cryptocurrency defines network consensus in the same way bitcoin does, then you cannot have a debt on an account.

Comment: @chytrik is right, there is no way to have an overdrawn withdrawal on your account.